# Java getDeskTop issue

Tags: java

Having a issue with `getDeskTop().open` / `.edit(file)` in that it is working properly on development drive by opening the file but when I move the application (jar) to another drive I get no error and no response. The paths are hardcoded "/home/temp/" + file, the application creates folders on start, basically the application is a personal version system serializes file contents to XML, when selected it deserializes then writes the file to a temp folder then calls `getDeskTop().open(file)`. The confusing part is that I also call `getDeskTop().open(file)` on the VersionControl.xml that the app creates and it works properly, checked the path vars to the file and they are correct. Here is the basic call, I get the path vars from a JTable cell:

```
case 2 :
    File fr = new File((String) jt.getModel().getValueAt(tmpRow, 2));
    javaxt.io.File ft = new javaxt.io.File((String)jt.getModel().getValueAt(tmpRow, 2));
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fr.toString());
    if (!AppVars.getIllegalExt().contains(ft.getExtension())) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().edit(fr);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    break;
```

It seems somehow I am missing a reference, the "Make" configuration is to extract dependencies into the jar.

Comment: What's the error/exception you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting an exception, the call to getDeskTop() does nothing.

Comment: It must be returning SOMETHING (as opposed to `null`) otherwise your `catch` block would be catching a `NullPointerException`. If the `edit()` method isn't doing anything then make sure you've reviewed its API documentation to ensure that the parameter is what it needs to be.

Comment: @Tenner thanks for replies, I have checked what is being sent to it, the proper path and file name is sent, it works when I send the VersionControl.xml path to it (opens my xml editor), and it works when I send the path to the directory to it (opens win explorer). I have checked the default application for the files - ok also. I can't figure out why it just fails with no indications of the problem.